# Write SQL Server stored procedure to insert off a select statement and loop through the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a novice at SQL and I am needing to write a stored procedure to take values from a select statement and insert a particular record based on the result.

Here it goes: my current select is this:

```
select distinct AcctId 
from tblGlAcctDtl 
where year = '2020' 
  and Period <> 5 
  and AcctId not in (select AcctId 
                     from tblGlAcctDtl 
                     where year = '2020' 
                       and Period = 5);
```

This query returns a list of accounts that do not have an existing entry for any period number I insert.

For example:

```
AcctId
---------
11400000
12200000
12300000
12500000
12600000
13000002
13000009
13000010
```

What I need: for each account returned I then need to write an entry for that period. These are the values I need to insert.

Sample data that I need to insert would look like this:

```
AcctId   Year   Period  Actual  ActualBase  Budget  Forecast Balance
--------------------------------------------------------------------
22100000 2020     5     0.000     0.000     0.000   0.000    0.000
27500000 2020     5     0.000     0.000     0.000   0.000    0.000
```

Any expert help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i would try:

```
-- Create a temp table

SELECT '2020' as year,'5' as Period, '0.000' as Actual,'0.000' as ActualBase,'0.000' as Budget,'0.000' as Forcast,'0.000' as Balance INTO #temp_table. 

--Create another temp table
select distinct AcctId 
INTO #account_ID
from tblGlAcctDtl 
where year = '2020' 
and Period <> 5 
and AcctId not in (select AcctId 
                   from tblGlAcctDtl 
                   where year = '2020' 
                   and Period = 5);
INSERT INTO Desired_table
SELECT * FROM #account_id CROSS JOIN  #temp_table
```

---

(From Question Poster) Here is the final version of what worked for me.

USE [TST]
DROP TABLE TempGlAcctDtl
DROP TABLE TempAccountId
GO

-- Create a temp table

SELECT '2020' as Year,'5' as Period, '0.000' as Actual,'0.000' as ActualBase,'0.000' as Budget,'0.000' as Forecast,'0.000' as Balance INTO TempGlAcctDtl
GO

--Create another temp table

select distinct AcctId INTO TempAccountId from tblGlAcctDtl where Year = '2020' and Period <> 5 and AcctId not in (select AcctId from tblGlAcctDtl where Year = '2020' and Period = 5);
INSERT INTO tblGlAcctDtl (AcctId, Year, Period, Actual, ActualBase, Budget, Forecast, Balance)
SELECT AcctId, Year, Period, Actual, ActualBase, Budget, Forecast, Balance FROM TempAccountId CROSS JOIN TempGlAcctDtl;
GO

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried your query, I had to make some tweaks to it as I was getting errors but they were minor.  It seems we are close but now I get this message after executing:   (1 row affected)

(262 rows affected)
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Completion time: 2019-12-18T16:48:19.9828485-06:00

Comment: So it seems to not like the table config, I am stuck on this one.  Here is the tweaked query:  USE [TST]
DROP TABLE TempGlAcctDtl
DROP TABLE TempAccountId
GO
SELECT '2020' as Year,'5' as Period, '0.000' as Actual,'0.000' as ActualBase,'0.000' as Budget,'0.000' as Forecast,'0.000' as Balance INTO TempGlAcctDtl
GO
select distinct AcctId INTO TempAccountId from tblGlAcctDtl where Year = '2020' and Period <> 5 and AcctId not in (select AcctId from tblGlAcctDtl where Year = '2020' and Period = 5);
INSERT INTO tblGlAcctDtl
SELECT * FROM TempAccountId CROSS JOIN TempGlAcctDtl
GO

Comment: Success, a little more messing around with your suggestion and I finally got it working.  Thank you very much.  I edited your post to add the final query that worked.